# calculate time difference using timediff function for 12 hour format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7

I am delphi developer.
I want to calculate difference between two time interval in 12 hours format.But it shows wrong result in mysql.
I have used TIMEDIFF function to calculate difference between time.
Eg. select TIMEDIFF('12:00:00','03:00:00');
It gives result as 09:00:00.
It should gives result as 03:00:00.

Please suggest the way to get right answer.

Comment: why don't you `convert()` it before `timediff()`?

Answer (score 0):

9 hrs is correct result for given parameters (12 -3 =9). If you want to get 3 hours, you can try  something like 
`SELECT TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE('03:00:00am','%h:%i:%S%p'),
STR_TO_DATE('12:00:00am','%h:%i:%S%p'));` .